# Pros and cons of different GraphQL syntax in typescript

Tags: typescript, express, graphql, apollo

I've been looking at quite a few different tutorials on GraphQL they are all written differently. I was wondering what the pros and cons are for all of them. Also, how would you modularize types, queries etc in different files? The first way that I've seen is by using a string to describe a GraphQL schema which is then exported and then imported into the schema file. This looks like this:

```
const typeDefs = `
type Query {
  testString: String
}
`;
```

Then there's the next way which uses the express-graphql package and uses objects to describe the schema. This looks like this:

```
const todoType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'todo',
  description: 'todo item',
  fields: () => ({
    itemId: {
      type: (GraphQLInt),
      description: 'The id of the todo.',
    },
    item: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The name of the todo.',
    },
    completed: {
      type: GraphQLBoolean,
      description: 'Completed todo? '
    }
  })
});
```

The other way that I've seen is by using graphql files.

Is it just personal preference or are there real benefits of using one over the other?

I understand that the first one I mentioned may lack syntax highlighting but this looks closest to actual graphql syntax. My preferred choice would be to use graphql files. But the problem is how to modularize it all? How would I merge several different .graphql files together and use them within a single schema?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use GraphQL with TypeScript in Node.js, you can take a look at [TypeGraphQL](https://github.com/19majkel94/type-graphql).

This tool will allow you to get rid of interfaces describing types, queries, mutation, args and inputs by defining typescript classes with decorators.
So you have only one source of truth, no need to jump over the codebase to add field, change its type, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Defining the query inside of a schema file or a string lets you prototype GraphQL interfaces quickly. This is very good to get started and implement some resolvers. When your schema grows the schema definition will also grow massively. We have only a couple of types but our schema file is over 1000 loc. This is why we define the types in JavaScript and also write the resolvers inside of the definition. Most resolvers are very simple and make use of data-loaders that contain the actual type resolving logic.
A [new tool by GraphCool](https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-import) allows imports in schema definitions. This kind of defeats my point above and allows to scale for another while with using the schema language.

Btw: There is syntax highlight for GraphQL schema definitions available e.g. in Atom through `language-babel`